# UniVerse 10.3 on Linux, file creation isn't acting as expected

Tags: universe

I'm getting a real strange thing:

I am issuing the TCL command

```
CREATE-FILE FNAME 30 7 1
```

UniVerse is creating the file but as a type 18?

Is this a bug in this version of UniVerse or have they not documented something?

Comment: Wrong kind of Tcl. The [tcl] tag is about Tool Command Language, not Terminal Control Language. Adjusting tags.

Comment: I am not able to replicate this. Not sure why you would want to specify the modulo and separation on a Dynamically hashed file, but when I ran your test and used ANALYZE.FILE on that new test file it showed Type 30 for me, though I am running a newer version of Universe as well. It 
 also might have something to do with whatever flavor the account is running under. I have spent most of my time in a Prime-centric world and non "INFORMATION.FORMAT" accounts may behave differently.  Rocket support might be helpful if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Peter this is a Universe database setup, so TCL is slightly different to what you are thinking.

Comment: Van, weirdly if I simply create a directory and make a VOC entry, it works fine ?????

Answer (score 0):

From UniVerse Help:

*The syntax of CREATE-FILE is slightly different in **PICK**, **REALTY**, and **IN2** flavor accounts from that used in **INFORMATION** and **IDEAL** flavor accounts.*

```
CREATE.FILE filename [dict.modula [,dict.separation [,dict.type]]] [data.modula [,data.separation [,data.type]]]
```

Thus, in your case

```
CREATE-FILE FNAME 30 7 1
```

is mean create a file with

dictionary file with modulo **30**.
data file with modulo **7**.

The last 1 is ignored.

since you didn't set data file type, so UniVerse take default file type **18**.